# How to get token from wordpress-rest-api using Retrofit Android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, wordpress-rest-api, jwt

I’m developing Android app that’s based on a WordPress website, so I need to get a token to login the user to the app using the JWT method.

When I send a request, I don’t get any response from the server; probably there something wrong with my code. I installed the `wordpress-rest-api` plugin and `jwt-auth-plugin` on the website.

My code contains `userModel.java` which contains getters and setters for the user id, email, and token.

**`retroFitInterface.java`:**

```java
@POST ("Authorization: Bearer")
Call<User> login (@Body Login login);

@GET ("secretinfo")
Call<ResponseBody>getSecret(@Header("Authorization")String authToken);
```

**`Login.java`:**

```java
private String email,password;
    public Login (String email,String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**`MainActivity.java`**

```java
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://taqoh.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
RetroFitInterface retroFitInterface = retrofit.create(RetroFitInterface.class);
private Button button, button1;

private static String token;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.get_token_btn);
}

private void login() {
    Login login = new Login("isohunter1@hotmail.com", "qweqweqwe123");
    Call<User>call = retroFitInterface.login(login);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                token = response.body().getToken();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

private void getSecret() {
    Call<ResponseBody>secret = retroFitInterface.getSecret(token);
    secret.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.login_btn) {
        login();
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.get_token_btn) {
        getSecret();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this site have an API endpoint? https://taqoh.com/ does not seem to be the correct endpoint. I had to click the Login/Register button and even then a popup came up with the Username/Password as the label names. I tried curl command `curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "Username=isohunter1@hotmail.com&Password=qweqweqwe123" 'https://taqoh.com'`. It just returns an HTML page. Please confirm if the site has an API for us to post data like the way you are doing. The resulting http status is 200 OK, however not what you want.

Comment: i tried adding the end point but still no response check the updated code

Comment: How did you add the endpoint? When I use the command `curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "Username=isohunter1@hotmail.com&Password=qweqweqwe123" 'https://taqoh.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token'`, it gives the following error : `{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}`, which tells me that the URL you are using has not been setup. Please check the URL again or set the correct URL and try again.